# Firefox multiple bookmarks rows

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, bookmarks

Is there a way in Firefox(latest ed.) to have multiple rows of bookmarks instead of the standard one? I've been looking around but one extension that worked with previous versions, no longer works(Multiple Rows).

Comment: Are you wanting a pointer to an extension that does this, or code for how to do it in an extension you are planning to write? Is this something you can solve by using the normal ability to put folders in that toolbar (which give dropdown menus of their contents/bookmarks/folders)? Or do you really need more individual, single click bookmarks?

Comment: I looked for a multiple rows of tabs for FF 57 and found a solution for your question for FF 57+: you need the file `@import url(./css/toolbars/bookmarks_toolbar_multiple_lines.css);` from https://github.com/aris-t2/customcssforfx and follow the instructions (This may help someone...)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is very easy and can be done in a few steps...

1. Go to the folder .../AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/YourProfile and create a new folder with the name "chrome" (has nothing to do with chrome browser).
2. Go into this folder and create a new text file inside it. Name the file "userChrome.css" (Make sure the name is userChrome.css, not userChrome.css.txt).
3. Write the following code into "userChrome.css":

   ```
   @-moz-document url-prefix("chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml") {
    #PersonalToolbar {
       max-height: calc(20px * 3) !important;
   }

   #personal-bookmarks,
   #PlacesToolbar,
   #PlacesToolbar > hbox {
       display: block;
   }

   #PersonalToolbar toolbarbutton {
       min-height: 20px !important;
       max-height: 20px !important;
   }

   #PlacesToolbarItems {
       max-height:60px!important;
       display: flex!important;
       flex-wrap: wrap!important;
       overflow-x: visible!important;
       overflow-y: auto!important;
   }

   #PlacesToolbar,
   #PersonalToolbar > scrollbar {
       -moz-window-dragging: no-drag !important;
   }

   #PlacesToolbar #PlacesChevron {
       display: none !important;
   }}
   ```
4. Restart your browser.
5. Type 'about:config' into the address bar and hit enter.
6. Then type in 'toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets'
7. Change the default value from 'false' to 'true' by double-clicking on it.
8. Restart your browser again.

This should be it. From now on, changes in your .css file will be displayed in Firefox. You can play around with the px values in the .css file to change the bookmark rows' heights or distances between them...

Comment: use this css instead https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/multi-row_bookmarks.css